# Why does destructor create a bug when it's being called?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory, destructor

I have created a Calendar class in which everything seems to be working fine but just before the program ends, when destructor is being called it causes a debug assertion fail!

This is the class:

```
    //constructor
Calendar::Calendar(const int *pday, const int *pmonth, const int *pyear){
    day = new int(sizeof(pday));
    month = new int(sizeof(pmonth));
    year = new int(sizeof(pyear));

    day = pday;
    month = pmonth;
    year = pyear;
}

//copy constructor
Calendar::Calendar(const Calendar &rhs){
    day = new int(sizeof(rhs.day));
    month = new int(sizeof(rhs.month));
    year = new int(sizeof(rhs.year));

    day = rhs.day;
    month = rhs.month;
    year = rhs.year;
}

//operator '=' overload
Calendar& Calendar::operator=(const Calendar &rhs){
    delete[] day;
    delete[] month;
    delete[] year;

    day = new int(sizeof(rhs.day));
    month = new int(sizeof(rhs.month));
    year = new int(sizeof(rhs.year));

    day = rhs.day;
    month = rhs.month;
    year = rhs.year;

    return *this;
}

//deconstructor
Calendar::~Calendar(){
    delete[] day;
    delete[] month;
    delete[] year;
}
```

What could be the problem? Am I not creating the memory for the variables of the class right ?

Comment: Why are you using `delete[]`? And why are you using pointers at all instead of ints?

Comment: new[size] maybe ? not new() or simply delete

Comment: Why is 4/4/4, or 8/8/8, your default date?

Comment: You should really start with a tutorial, and if possible one that avoids new and delete until you grasp other concepts... By the time you get to `new` it might become aparent that in `new T(arg)`, `arg` is unrelated to the size of the memory being allocated.

Comment: Get rid of `sizeof()` and use `delete` instead of `delete []`. Although you should not be using pointers and dynamic allocation for this class at all.

Comment: I m using dynamic allocation because I ve been asked to ... Also, I saw new combined with sizeof exactly like this at a tutorial! I guess it was not a good one.Also it was using delete[] on the destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at your copy constructor:

```
Calendar::Calendar(const Calendar &rhs){
    day = new int(sizeof(rhs.day));
    month = new int(sizeof(rhs.month));
    year = new int(sizeof(rhs.year));

    day = rhs.day;
    month = rhs.month;
    year = rhs.year;
}
```

First you allocate memory and assign them to your members. Then you overwrite the pointer in this object with the pointers from the `rhs` object, leading you to have two object both pointing to the same memory. When one of the objects is destructed the other objects will have stray pointers, trying to delete them will lead to *undefined behavior*

One solution is to use dereferencing to copy the values, e.g.

```
*day = *rhs.day;
```

But I really see no need for pointers at all here, which means you don't need to allocate memory, you don't need to worry about copying, you don't have to worry about stray pointers of memory leaks. In fact, if you don't have pointers, you don't even need a copy-constructor, assignment operator or destructor. I recommend you read about [the rule of zero](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Answer (score 4):

When you create a pointer with `new` you delete it with `delete`.  When you create a pointer with `new[]` you delete it with `delete[]`.  Mixing them is undefined behavior and that is what you are doing.  You create the pointer with `new` but you delete it with `delete[]`

I believe you meant to create the pointers like

```
day = new int;
month = new int;
year = new int;
```

Why are you using pointers here?  Using pointers does not seem the way to do here.  A simple `Calendar` class that stores the day, month and year can be implemented as

```
Calendar
{
private:
    int day_;
    int month_;
    int year_;
public:
    Calendar(int day = 0, int month = 0, int year = 0) : day_(day), month_(month), year_(year) {}
};
```

And now  the default copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor will work for you and there are no pointers to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not constructing the data correctly.

```
day = pday;
month = pmonth;
year = pyear;
```

is a pointer assignment, copying the address from the parameters, not their values.

The correct way is (assuming we want to copy 1 element):

```
*day = *pday;
*month = *pmonth;
*year = *pyear;
```

You are also mixing array delete `delete[]` with single element `new` (without `[]`). That is undefined behavior.

And another thing, `day = new int(sizeof(pday));` creates an `int` initialized with a value that is the size of a pointer. That seems very odd.